# Помогите с калькулятором комплексных чисел Python

Tags: python, ооп, калькулятор, класс

Пишу калькулятор комплексных чисел, реализующий основные математические операции. Получилось так, вроде все работает:

```
class MathComplex:
    def __init__(self, real=0, imag=0):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag        
        
    def __abs__(self):        
        return MathComplex((self.real**2 + self.imag**2)**0.5)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        real = self.real if self.real != 0 else ""
        imag = "" if self.imag == 0 or abs(self.imag) == 1 else abs(self.imag)
        i_sign = "i" if self.imag != 0 else ""
        sign = "+" if self.imag > 0 and self.real != 0 else "-" if self.imag < 0 else ""
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(real, sign, imag,i_sign)
       
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real + other.real, self.imag + other.imag)
    
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real - other.real, self.imag - other.imag)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag, self.real*other.imag + self.imag*other.real)
    
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        real = (self.real*other.real + self.imag*other.imag) / (other.real**2 + other.imag**2)
        imag = (self.imag*other.real - self.real*other.imag) / (other.real**2 + other.imag**2)
        return MathComplex(real, imag)

    def __neg__(self):
        return MathComplex(self.imag)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.real == other.real and self.imag == other.imag:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __round__(self, n):
        
        return MathComplex(round(self.real, n), round(self.imag, n))

    def conjugate(self):
        self.imag = - self.imag
        return MathComplex()
```

Запинка в следующем пункте:

В математике у нас определены выражения вида (1+5i) + 42. Если перевести это на язык объектов питона, то мы к комплексному числу прибавляем объект int. Нужно отнаследовать класс ExtendedComplex и реализовать в нем соответствующие специальные методы, чтобы арифметические операции выполнялись еще и с операндами типа int/float. Немного подробнее: если а - объект любого из классов (int, float, ExtendedComplex), x - экземпляр ExtendedComplex, то должны выполняться оба выражения x + a и a + x.

Имею следующие мысли:

```
class ExtendedComplex(MathComplex):

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real + other, self.imag)
    def __radd__(self, other):
            pass
```

Не понимаю как написать код с `__radd__` . Через переменную-ошибку как-то или иначе... Сам синтаксис не понимаю как реализуется.

Спрашиваю для одной операции, понятно что остальные условно по аналогии пойдут.

Пожалуйста, не отправляйте меня в интернет и вот
[сюда](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/peregruzka-operatorov.html), мне не помогло.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю для чего вам это, в своё время я сам писал калькулятор комплексных чисел, но там у меня была задача полного отображения последовательности математических действий. А так пайтон имеет уже реализованные методы работы с комплексными числами и позволяет выполнять все доступные математические действия, если ваша задача состоит в этом, то делаете лишнюю работу.

Comment: `pass` -> `return MathComplex(other + self.real, self.imag)`.

Comment: Добрый день, разбираюсь в теме классов. Затем и делаю. 

Понятно, что все эти действия можно выполнить через cmath :)

Comment: Поправьте так же реализацию метода \_\_eq\_\_, вы делаете проверку в блоке if и если она равна True входите в тело блока и только там возвращаете True, вместо этого просто возвращайте результат проверки `return self.real == other.real and self.imag == other.imag`

Comment: @kristal благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не совсем понятно с какой целью вы делаете ещё один класс наследник, вы реалезуете класс для работы с комплексными числами, так зачем его дробить на несколько классов?
Что касается вашего вопроса с перегрузкой оператора `__radd__`, всё предельно просто:

```
class ExtendedComplex(MathComplex):

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real + other, self.imag)
    def __radd__(self, other):
            return self.__add__(other)
```

В случае если вы уже реализовали метод `__add__`, то, дабы не дублировать код несколько раз мы можем просто вызвать его, передав наши параметры, ведь в аргументе `other` всегда будет число, которое мы хотим прибавить к числу, у которого вызывается метод `__add__` или `__radd__` тобишь `self`. Получилось немного запутанно, попробую пояснить на примере:

```
a + b
```

Эта запись будет эквивалентна следующей:

```
a.__add__(b)
```

Если ещё точнее, то у экземпляра объекта `a` мы вызываем метод `__add__` и передаём в качестве параметра `b`. Следовательно, наш `a` внутри метода `__add__` будет представлен как `self`, а `b` т.к. передавался в качестве параметров будет представлен как `other`. Представим следующий код:

```
a = ExtendedComplex(140, 2)
a + 7
```

Тут всё следует примеру выше. У экземпляра `a` вызывается метод `__add__` и передаётся в качестве аргумента 7. Но что если...

```
a = ExtendedComplex(140, 2)
7 + a
```

`7` является экземпляром класса `int`, но т.к. он является системным классом он не знает как себя вести с экземпляром класса `ExtendedComplex` при сложении. Тут нам приходит на помощь метод `__radd__`. Если попытка вызова метода `__add__` у класса `int` не увенчалась успехом, то Python идёт в класс `ExtendedComplex` и пытается вызвать у него метод `__radd__`. Тобишь `a.__radd__(7)`, ничего не напоминает?) Перегрузка оператора `__radd__` необходима для правильного выполнения операции сложения, когда объект класса ExtendedComplex находится вторым аргументом, а не первым.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я думаю тоже зашью это в один класс. 2 класса делать бессмысленно, но видимо тут у меня тренировочная задача, видимо, еще посмотреть как наследование работает, пусть и не очень логичная в прикладном плане.

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации метода **radd** в классе ExtendedComplex нужно просто вернуть результат сложения объекта other и экземпляра ExtendedComplex.
class ExtendedComplex(MathComplex):

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real + other, self.imag)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)
```

Определяете **radd**, который будет вызван в случае, если слева от оператора + находится объект типа, отличного от MathComplex (т.е. int или float). Внутри метода **radd** мы просто вызываем метод **add** и передаем ему аргументы в обратном порядке, т.е. сначала other, а затем self.

Comment: То есть получается питон автоматически обращается к методу radd, если add не прошел по типам, никаких  переходов не требуется, если я верно понимаю.

Comment: @Blbrd173512 Да, eсли операция + не может быть выполнена между объектами первого и второго аргументов, то Python пытается выполнить операцию, используя метод __radd__ второго аргумента. Если метод __radd__ второго аргумента не определен, Python генерирует исключение TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось вот так с учетом того что посоветовали, одним классом и с магическими методами:

```
class MathComplex:
    def __init__(self, real=0, imag=0):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag        
        
    def __abs__(self):        
        return MathComplex((self.real**2 + self.imag**2)**0.5)
        if isinstance(self, (int, float)):
            return(abs(self))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        real = self.real if self.real != 0 else ""
        imag = "" if self.imag == 0 or abs(self.imag) == 1 else abs(self.imag)
        i_sign = "i" if self.imag != 0 else ""
        sign = "+" if self.imag > 0 and self.real != 0 else "-" if self.imag < 0 else ""
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(real, sign, imag,i_sign)
       
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real + other.real, self.imag + other.imag)
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real + other, self.imag)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)
    
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real - other.real, self.imag - other.imag)
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real - other.real, self.imag)
        
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__sub__(other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MathComplex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag, self.real*other.imag + self.imag*other.real)
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(other*self.real, other*self.imag)
        
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
    
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        real = (self.real*other.real + self.imag*other.imag) / (other.real**2 + other.imag**2)
        imag = (self.imag*other.real - self.real*other.imag) / (other.real**2 + other.imag**2)
        return MathComplex(real, imag)
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return MathComplex(self.real / other, self.imag / other)
        
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return self.__truediv__(other)

    def __neg__(self):
        return MathComplex(self.imag)
        if isinstance(self, (int, float)):
            return 'Отсутствует мнимая часть'
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.real == other.real and self.imag == other.imag

    def __round__(self, n):
        
        return MathComplex(round(self.real, n), round(self.imag, n))

    def conjugate(self):
        self.imag = - self.imag
        return MathComplex()
        if isinstance(self, (int, float)):
            return 'Отсутствует мнимая часть'           

e = MathComplex()
a = MathComplex(2, 1)
b = MathComplex(4, 3)
d = 4
x = 4.67

assert str(a + e) == str(b + MathComplex(-2, -2)),
assert str(a - e) == str(a)
assert a - e == a
assert str(b * a) == str(MathComplex(5, 10))
assert str(b / a) == str(MathComplex(2.2, 0.4))
assert str(a + e) == str(e + a)
assert str(a - d) == str(MathComplex(-2, 1))
assert a - x == MathComplex(-2.67, 1)
assert str(b * d) == str(d * b)
assert round(abs(b / x), 4) == 1.0707
```